# Formatting a date in R without leading zeros

Tags: r, date, zero-pad

Is there a way to use the `format` function on a date object, specifically an object of class `POSIXlt`, `POSIXct`, or `Date`, with the format `%Y, %m, %d` such that leading zeros are stripped from each of those 3 fields?

For example, I would like `format(as.Date("1998-09-02"), "%Y, %m, %d")` to return `1998, 9, 2` and not `1998, 09, 02`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just remove the leading zeros at the end:

```
gsub(" 0", " ", format(as.Date("1998-09-02"), "%Y, %m, %d"))
## [1] "1998, 9, 2"
```

Use [%e](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) to obtain a leading space instead of a leading zero.

Comment: It's weird to me that there isn't just an option like `%D` or whatever that removes leading zeros.

Comment: may as well make that `fixed = TRUE`

Comment: See RyanFrost's post [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62159914/5851018) for a better solution that uses `strftime`'s own formatting.

Comment: This requires there to be a blank space before the 0. If you remove that part of the token being matched then it would mess up every date that ends in 0 like 10, 20, 30. I do not recommend this approach.

Comment: @Fons MA, @Hack=R., `%#d` and `%-d` are platform specific and do not work on my Windows machine.  The solution in this answer works on all platforms.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this with a simple change to your `strftime` format string. However, it depends on your platform (Unix or Windows).

#### Unix

Insert a minus sign (`-`) before each term you'd like to remove leading zeros from:

```r
format(as.Date("2020-06-02"), "%Y, %-m, %-d")
[1] "2020, 6, 2"
```

#### Windows

Insert a pound sign (`#`) before each desired term:

```r
format(as.Date("2020-06-02"), "%Y, %#m, %#d")
[1] "2020, 6, 2"
```

Comment: I like the look of this sollution, however, it does not work for me (on Windows):> format(as.Date("2020-06-02"), "%Y, %m, %d")
[1] "2020, 06, 02"
> format(as.Date("2020-06-02"), "%Y, %#m, %#d")
[1] "2020, #m, #d" I wonder why...

Comment: This is by far the best solution

Comment: this works great for me

Comment: it doesn't work on two Windows machines I have but I have the impression it's an issue related to the locale settings...

Comment: This doesn't work on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 11):

I have discovered a workaround by using `year()`, `month()` and `day()` function of [{lubridate} package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/). With the help of [`glue::glue()`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/), it is easy to do it as following:

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(glue)
dt <- "1998-09-02"
glue("{year(dt)}, {month(dt)}, {day(dt)}")
#> 1998, 9, 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Edit on 2023-03-02:

After {tidyverse} 2.0.0, {lubridate} is attached after attaching {tidyverse}, so there is no need to attach {lubridate} now:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dt <- "1998-09-02"
str_glue("{year(dt)}, {month(dt)}, {day(dt)}")
#> 1998, 9, 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If {tidyverse} is used (suggested by @banbh), then `str_glue()` can be used:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
dt <- "1998-09-02"
str_glue("{year(dt)}, {month(dt)}, {day(dt)}")
#> 1998, 9, 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Also, if you've loaded the `tidyverse` package (or just `stringr`) then you can use `str_glue()` instead of `glue()` and avoiding loading the `glue` package.

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution using gsub, to remove leading zeros from the day or month digits produced by %m or %d. This deletes any zero that is not preceded by a digit:

```
gsub("(\\D)0", "\\1", format(as.Date("1998-09-02"), "%Y, %m, %d"))
```